# Is there a way to generate working Code128 barcodes in TD 6.3?

Tags: barcode, code128, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I am currently working on a project that requires the output of a Code128 barcode to a QRP.
It's an older project ported from TD 4.1, it previously used a barcode.dll that doesn't work properly with 6.3.

Since I couldn't find a DLL that would work, I decided to try and use the Code128bWin project from the Sample Vault (https://samples.tdcommunity.net/index.php?dir=&file=Code128bWin.zip).
Now, the problem is, the function used there generates barcodes just fine, but they're not scannable and I can't figure out why.

I'm still fairly new to Team Developer, so maybe the problem is totally obvious and I'm just not seeing it, or maybe there is a simpler way to generate the barcode, but I've been stumped on this for days now, and getting nowhere.

I would be appreciative of any help.

Comment: Example output from the barcodes that won't scan would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with the obvious - have you tried a UNICODE version of your 'barcode.dll' , as TD6.3 is UNICODE based,  or maybe your existing one is UNICODE compliant, but 'not working properly' as you haven't changed your TD string parameters and buffer sizes to UNICODE in your api calls.
e.g. String: LPSTR  becomes  String: LPWSTR  and also bear in mind SalSetBufferLength(20) before an api call will allocate 20 bytes of storage, but be aware that 2 of these bytes will be used as a null terminator.  Therefore, to send /receive the barcode string '*4>HR\fpzg' you would need to give the buffer 22 bytes of storage.   Could be why your existing dll is not working properly.